# how to customize next_posts_link link in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using

```
           <?php next_posts_link( '&larr; Next' ); ?>
```

for pagination in wordpress ,it works ,but how to customize it ,I prefer a button for next but now it appears as 'Next →'

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Refer this site:**

[next_posts_link](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/next_post_link)

Comment: it works next_posts_link( '<input type=button value=NEXT/>' );